# OpenCV can not find library on launch. Backwards compatibility?

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I am trying to build and use a piece of `C++` code that uses OpenCV. I am working on Linux, working in `Code::Blocks` (and the code was originally also developed on a Linux platform using `C::B`).

I followed [this](http://www.raben.com/book/export/html/3) to install OpenCV (Ubuntu 12.04 & OpenCV 2.4.3). The project compiles fine, but when I try to execute it, it crashes on launch, with the following message about how it can not find the library:

```
(file_address): error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.3: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.017 s Press ENTER to continue.
```

I set all the parameters for the linker according to several `Code::Blocks` install tutorials.

I also checked in `/usr/local/lib/` for my libraries (it is the folder I gave to Code::Blocks' compiler); and while I do have a `libopencv_core.so`, a `libopencv_core.so.2.4` and a `libopencv_core.2.4.3`, I do not have a `libopencv_core.so.2.3`.

So I'm wondering what the issue is. Is it about backwards compatibility, i.e. do I have to install the exact same version of OpenCV used to develop the original code? (This would be a bit concerning, since I am trying to make a widely-usable library).

Could I force it to use `libopencv_core.so.2.4` instead?

EDIT: I managed to make it work by removing everything and reinstalling with a simple apt-get. Sometimes it's the simplest method that works the best! From now on I'll try to apt-get before following installation tutorials. ;)

Have a nice day!